# How to delete non-existent apps which wanted access in past from privacy menu

Tags: big-sur, privacy

For example, these:

[image]

These apps were deleted, but they still display in privacy menu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you restarted your Mac after deleting the apps? Did those apps come with some sort of uninstaller? Maybe simply deleting them is not enough to uninstall them...

Comment: I didn't remember if they had uninstallers or not. I don't know even what is the second app.